# Cancel Windows 10 BackgroundDownloader

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'd like to implement a timeout functionality for BackgroundDownloader. When I reach timeout i **can't cancel download operation**. So I use it like so:

```
   public async void downloadFile(string fileUrl, string fileName) {
        var myFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path);
        var myFile = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        var downloadOperation = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(fileUrl), myFile);

        var task = Task.Run(async () => await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask());
        if ( task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)) ) {
            // file is downloaded in time

        } else {
            // timeout is reached - how to cancel downloadOperation ?????

        }
    }
```

I was trying :

```
downloadOperation.StartAsync().Cancel();
```

I get

> WinRT information: This operation was already started. Call
>   AttachAsync to attach to a running download/upload.

```
downloadOperation.AttachAsync().Cancel();
```

I get

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in
>   Project.exe WinRT information: This operation was not started. Call
>   StartAsync to start the operation.Additional information: A method was
>   called at an unexpected time.

Any ideas will be apreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I reach timeout i can't cancel download operation. I was trying : downloadOperation.AttachAsync().Cancel();

Based on my test, `downloadOperation.AttachAsync().Cancel();` works fine on my site. Following is the code I used for testing:

```
public async void downloadFile(string fileUrl, string fileName)
{
    var myFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path);
    var myFile = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
    var downloadOperation = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(fileUrl), myFile);

    var task = Task.Run(async () => await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask());
    if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)))
    {
        // file is downloaded in time
    }
    else {
        // timeout is reached - how to cancel downloadOperation ?????
        downloadOperation.AttachAsync().Cancel();
    }
}
```

Usually we use [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) to cancel the download operation. Besides, using [Task.Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx) method will **block UI thread**, and this causes a bad user experience. So using [CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194893(v=vs.110).aspx) method may be a better choice in your scenario.

Following is the code I have verified:

```
public async void downloadFile(string fileUrl, string fileName)
{
    var myFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path);
    var myFile = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
    var downloadOperation = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(fileUrl), myFile);

    // Define the cancellation token.
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

    cts.CancelAfter(1000);
    try
    {
        // Pass the token to the task that listens for cancellation.
        await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(token);
        // file is downloaded in time
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // timeout is reached, downloadOperation is cancled
    }
    finally
    {
        // Releases all resources of cts
        cts.Dispose();
    }
}
```